# Spark History server not listing completed jars

Tags: apache-spark, logging, configuration, monitoring

I'm running Spark standalone jobs in Windows. I would like to monitor my Spark jobs using the spark history server. I have launched spark history server with below command and history server is successfully launched.

```
C:\Users\Documents\Prev_D_Folder\Softwares\Softwares\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
```

[image]

I ran spark job locally but history server does not list any completed jobs.

My spark spark-defaults.conf file content is:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///C:/Users/m1047320/Documents/logs
spark.history.provider = org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:///C:/Users/m1047320/Documents/logs-hist
```

I have read, write and execute permissions for both log directories.

Answer (score 0):

The directory for `spark.eventLog.dir` and `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` should be the same.

From the documentation, [`spark.eventLog.dir`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui) is the log base directory:

> Base directory in which Spark events are logged, if spark.eventLog.enabled is true. Within this base directory, Spark creates a sub-directory for each application, and logs the events specific to the application in this directory [...]

While [`spark.history.fs.logDirectory`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) configures the directory the history server uses to read logs:

> For the filesystem history provider, the URL to the directory containing application event logs to load.

The reason you can't find any completed jobs is due to the history server reading an empty directory.

Comment: I mentioned same directory path for spark.eventLog.dir and  spark.history.fs.logDirectory as file:///C:/tmp/spark-events. Sill no jobs are listed by history server

Comment: @Niketa: Can you see log files for the jobs being created in the folder?

Comment: No, there are no log files created in the folder

Comment: @Niketa: Then it's not an issue with the history server but the logging itself. It may be obvious but just in case, make sure you run some jobs that will produce logs after changing the log folder. Also, did you get an logs previously (in Users/m1047320/Documents/logs or other places)?

Comment: No logs are not created in folder but as soon as run spark application c/tmp/spark-events/ folder's Date modified gets updated. I am surprised why the logs are not created

Comment: @Niketa: Yes, it seems a bit strange. Make sure the config file is actually being used (the /tmp/spark-events fodler is the default so that do not prove it). The default config directory is `SPARK_HOME/conf`.

Comment: @Niketa: did you manage to solve the problem? I'm curious what more in addition to the folder issue I pointed out that casued the history server to be empty.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Unfortunately issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

all the settings posted in question remain the same along with what I need to add
-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=file:///C:/sparkhistorylogs -Dspark.eventLog.dir=file:///C:/sparkhistorylogs

while submitting spark application or configure in Vmoptions in intelliji.

I missed above step hence history server was not showing completed jobs. Now i am able access completed job's info through history server at https://localhost:18080